# Facebook ads api workflow

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, ads, facebook-access-token

My app got white-listed for using the Ads API.

I was wondering in regarding to the authentication flow.
Say, that I need to retrieve and execute actions via the API on daily tasks ( with no user interaction) , I find the authentication process quite cumbersome.

Is there a way to work with my app access token instead of a user access token?
I want to be able to approve my app only once for each user and then to be able to work with no user interaction.
Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App access token is not relevant for this case.

I had to work with the user access token. 
I followed this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/

Eventually , one should use some client side code in order to get a user permissions and then make another request for getting the user token.

So you'll have to call
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=ads_management,offline_access&**response_type=code**

Get the authentication code and make another call:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE

Then you'll get an access token which is **valid only for two months**, in opposed to what Facebook docs says in here:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

"Ads APIs are special cased to allow collection of statistics offline. PMD partners should use server-side OAuth flow in order to receive a **non-expiring token** rather than a token that has longer expiration time."

Too bad that the access token is not really valid forever...

Answer (score 1):

According to "Exception 4" in [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) , if you have Ads API access you should be able to get a non-expiring token if you use the correct workflow. Following the [guidelines outlined here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending), if you use the server side OAuth flow, to make the following request you should get a non-expiring token:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Answer (score 1):

thx for the feedback regarding the Access token process being cumbersome. Because this is a one to many solution - a single App ID can manage multiple ad accounts, on behalf of multiple people - we need to make calls on behalf of people.

You should be able to get a persistent access token for Ads API. If you are not getting it, please provide exact steps you are following so we can see if there is a bug or you might be missing a step.

Thx.

Comment: I have the same problem. Where should I report this issue?